# List validation in Sharepoint

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to build a formula which is applied to multiple fields in a list. The logic is as follows:

If alternative "a" in choice field "b" is selected, then make input value in field "c" mandatory.

I need to repeat this logic for multiple input fields (as "c"), where selection "a" in choice field "b" remains a constant condition.

Let's say I have 5 fields that needs to be mandatory when "a" in choice field "b" is selected.

How do I build this into one formula?

I don't have much programming experience besides simple logic statements in Excel and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood all your requirements. But, here is example formula which will give you idea to create your own formula based on the logic.

```
=IF([Column B] = "A", IF(OR(ISBLANK([Column C]),ISBLANK([Column D]),ISBLANK([Column E])),FALSE,TRUE))
```

**Exaplanation**: If value of Column B is equal to A, Column C, Column D and Column E will be mandatory.

For more information about available functions in SharePoint formula, check this Microsoft official documentation: [Examples of common SharePoint list formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)